# How to give access to selective class methods in inheritance?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

We have a base class A which consists of 6 public methods :

```
public class A
{ 
 public void method1()
 {
  // Implementation
 }

 public void method2()
 {
   // Implementation
 }
 .
 . 
 .
 .
 public void method6()
 {
  // Implementation
 }
}
```

We have two child class B and C which inherits from A. How can I implement it in such a way that Class B has access to only method1(),method2(),method3() and Class C has access to method4(),method5(),method6()??

Comment: You can't, basically. They're public methods - *anything* can call them, regardless of inheritance. It sounds like you may want two separate classes here really...

Comment: then you need two class. class `A1` is parent of `B` and `A2` is parent of `C` and both `A1` and `A2` inherit class `A`  or implement interface `IA`

Comment: Composition is the way to go I think

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Answer (score 15):

You can't prevent something from using public class `A` methods, but you can definitely hide them with the proper use of interfaces.

```
interface IAOne 
{
    void method1();
    void method2();
    void method3();
}

interface IATwo 
{
    void method4();
    void method5();
    void method6();
}

class A : IAOne, IATwo
{
    void method1() { }
    void method2() { }
    void method3() { }
    void method4() { }
    void method5() { }
    void method6() { }
}
```

So now you have class `B` which never needs to know about `A` or about `A`'s methods. It only knows about the `IAOne` interface. B can now also re-expose any methods (and even re-implement the interface) and delegate the implementation of those to `A`.

```
class B : IAOne 
{
    private IAOne _a;
    public B(IAOne a) { _a = a; }

    void method1() { _a.method1(); }
    void method2() { _a.method2(); }
    void method3() { _a.method3(); }
}
```

Comment: But in this case, I wont be using class A right? So that does'nt solve the purpose !!!

Comment: @SriramM Based on what is in your question it does. If there is a reason this does not work, then your question was bad, and didn't properly lay out the requirements.

Comment: This is the correct solution: judicious use of interfaces, and composition instead of inheritance.

Answer (score 9):

You basically can't do that. The fact that you're attempting to do it should serve as a warning that there is something wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't now why you have emphasize to use one class (A) with all 6 methods, but if you wanna get that may you should aspect programming design and put and interceptor on the head of your methods. Then you can check caller with MethodCallerInfo and control to each your child classes just call their own methods